# Is there a difference in the way DDLs and DMLs are implemented by a database?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design, plsql

DDLs and DMLs are two strict categories of types of statements used for interacting with a database. I am not sure why this categorization exists.

Is there a fundamental difference in the way an Oracle database would work internally with respect to a DDL and DML statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One major (technical) difference between DDL and DML in Oracle is, that DDL is **not** transactional, i.e. they cannot be rolled back and don't require a commit. As a matter of fact DDL in Oracle does an implicit commit before it's executed.

Other databases (e.g. Postgres, DB2) do not make a difference with regards to transactions between DDL and DML

After all it's just a categorization, similar to the terms "application" and "server" (as in database server). From an operating point of view, OpenOffice and Oracle are both simply "applications", but yet we classify them into different categories.

Comment: A nit: in Oracle DDL is transactional, but can not take part in multi-statement transactions. There is an implicit commit before execution and after successful completion of execution. In the case of an error during execution, Oracle can roll the incomplete DDL back, making them atomic.

Answer (score 1):

DDL statements are used to define database structures, objects, and schemas whereas DML statements are used for managing data within schema objects.  At the end of the day, Oracle (o r any other data management system) would process each type statement according to security permissions and object availability (i.e. locks on tables / views and isolation levels).

Also, schema definitions are held in internal master tables so your DDL statements actually affect the data stored in those tables and perhaps can be considered "master DML" statements in that sense.

Answer (score 1):

If your question amounts to "is there a reason why it is *necessary* for DDL and DML to "be implemented differently", the answer is "NO".

However, the definers of the SQL language have opted for making DDL syntactically distinct.  As a consequence, adding a column to a table must be done through the appropriate ALTER TABLE command.  A side-effect of that command is that a row gets inserted in the catalog table that documents all columns.  Stress *side-effect*.

But there is no fundamental reason why the insertion of a row in the catalog table could not be *the trigger itself* for the column addition, thus entirely eliminating the need for any "dedicated DDL".